# updated array of objects sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

In my mongodb had collections Category as: [{catid: 1, id:1 }, {catid:1, id:2 },{catid:1, id: 3},{catid:1, id:4},{catid:2}]

How to using update method as: Category.update({catid:1}, [{catid:1, status:'sick'},{catid:1, status:'angry'},{catid: 1, status: 'boring'}, {catid: 1, status: 'happy'}]).exec(function(Err, updated){})

thanks all!

Comment: Providing us with your Category model would help.

Comment: sample of code for model and controller would be of great help